# Use TF.JS model in regular TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Is it possible to use a TensorFlow.JS models from regular TensorFlow? Some of them like FaceMesh have no direct counterparts available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have any tools to convert from TensorFlow.js format to Python compatible format.

We only have the ability to go from Python -> JavaScript right now to the best of my knowledge (most folk want to take some research written in Python and use it in JS land vs the other way around).

Comment: Problem is some models such as FaceMesh are released only in JS format.

Comment: Come join JS land, we have Cookies :-) (document.cookie). A lot more models are only in Python (still dominant for research) so hey, goes both ways. I hope in the future models will be language agnostic for inference at least. We shall have to see how it goes. For now though you would have to use MediaPipe if you want a non JS version but that may be harder to use.